# Can voltage be considered simply a conversion factor?

Tags: classical-mechanics, energy, voltage

Please correct my logic or lack thereof.  It seems to me voltage or potential difference is only a conversion factor between charge and energy.  Here's an example:  Suppose 10 elementary charges are in one place and 2 are in another.  If I measure the voltage I read 8 charges difference.  The distance between the charges doesn't matter in regard to energy because it will take the same energy to move charges no matter how far away they are.  If they are close it will take a lot of energy in a short distance.  If they are far away it will take much less energy but over a longer distance. So the only factor determining the voltage is the number of charges difference.  Therefore the units of voltage should be $n$ and unitless where $n =$ the number of elementary charges difference between the two places.  This means charge really is measure of potential energy and a conversion factor can be used to convert to joules.  I'm sure I'm missing something here.  Let me know what you think.

Comment: No, voltage or potential difference is not only a conversion factor between charge and energy. The potential difference, $V$, between two points is defined as the work required per unit charge to move the charge between the two points. Consequently, all your other statements based on that assumption are incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's an example: Suppose 10 elementary charges are in one place and 2 are in another. If I measure the voltage I read 8 charges difference. The distance between the charges doesn't matter in regard to energy because it will take the same energy to move charges no matter how far away they are.

This is not correct. The distance does matter substantially. In fact, if you have a spherical shell of radius $R$ with charge $Q$ then the voltage at the center [is given by](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/potsph.html) $$V=\frac{Q}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 R}$$ So the distance between the charges is important. The smaller the distance the larger the voltage.

Of course, a spherical shell is not a good approximation of 2 charges or 10 charges, but it would be a fine approximation of 2 million or 10 million. So you could easily have more voltage with the smaller number of charges as long as the radius of the small number of charges is less than 1/5 the radius of the large number of charges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'll look into the sphere idea in more depth.  At the fundamental level I'm not convinced though.  Going back to the 10 and 2 elementary charges separated by some distance r.  The force between them is q^2/r^2 leaving out conversion factors.  Taking the square root of each side leaves q/r and the root of the force F.  The root of F is still a force, just smaller.  Moving r to the other side leaves q=rootF * r.  RootF*r is force x distance =work.  So this shows that charge = work or energy and this seems to prove my point that voltage is a unitless conversion factor.

Comment: @johnm2021 That is the force between each pair. But in the first case there is 1 pair and in the second case there are 45 pairs. In any case, go ahead and work it out in terms of point charges. The conclusion is the same, it is just more complicated math. The voltage at the origin depends on how close the charges are to the origin, so it is not just proportional to the number of charges.

Comment: I'm not understanding your answer.  The sphere equation you show is the root of the force equation.  F=q2/r2, V=q/r.  The root of q is still a charge.  The root of distance is still a distance.  Why is the root of force a voltage?  If you put R on the other side of the equation V*R=Q.  Energy = Force x distance.  In this case Q is energy, R distance and V is force.  It seems the sphere equation proves my point.

Comment: @johnm2021 first, voltage is not force nor the root of force. You are neglecting the proportionality constants in front. Second your stated point is “the only factor determining the voltage is the number of charges”. The formula clearly shows this statement is false.